# USCIS Processing Times

Tags: usa, api, labor, migration

Can I get the USCIS Processing Times by Service Center via the API? For example, the I-140 processing times for the Nebraska Service Center. https://egov.uscis.gov/cris/processingTimesDisplay.do

Comment: what is your example showing/supposed to do? that link renders a blank document. i'm assuming its an api call?

Comment: does uscis even have an api? their site search and search engine search is turning up nothing.